# Golang "syscall/js" build constrains in project

Tags: go, webassembly

I am working on a web browser multiplayer game in golang. The backend is in go, and the frontend is in go, compiled to wasm.

I am importing syscall/js in a bunch of my files in order to interact with the browser context outside of wasm, such as WebSockets, inputs, and canvas.

I have the error "error while importing syscall/js: build constraints exclude all Go files in /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js".

I created this shell script to help run it

```bash
echo "Building client WASM binary..."

# Build the client (WASM target)
go env -w GOOS=js GOARCH=wasm
go build -o ./public/main.wasm ./public/main.go

echo "Build complete. Starting server..."

# Run the server (Linux target)
go env -w GOOS=linux GOARCH=amd64
go run ./main.go
```

So when I am running it normally, my GOOS is linux and GOARCH is amd64.
This causes the error "error while importing syscall/js: build constraints exclude all Go files in /usr/local/go/src/syscall/js". If I set the env to GOOS=js and GOARCH=wasm, the error disappears.
However I don't want my GOOS or GOARCH set to wasm configurations all the time.

Is there anything I can do to get this error to disappear, keep intellisense, and not have my go env set to WASM configuration when I'm working on the backend.

Comment: Import syscall/js only when building for js/wasm. Your "normal" build cannot include syscall/js so guard that import (put everything that needs and imports syscall/js into one file and include only if building for js/wasm.)

Comment: @Volker The file structure is a main folder with the backend main.go and a server folder, and then a public folder with its own main.go and subfolders. I have both of them open in the parent folder in VS Code. Syscall imports are only in files which need them, not even most of them, and only in the public folder(s). Is there a way to turn the error off for those files or something? It's not crucial but very annoying.

Comment: Yes, use [build constraints](https://pkg.go.dev/cmd/go#hdr-Build_constraints) to skip files with `syscall/js` when not building for that architecture (this should be done when importing any os/architecture architecture specific packages, not just js/wasm)